# How to map in Hibernate a qualified association?

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, hibernate-mapping

I tried to map this three classes:

```
@Entity
class Photo {
...
@ManyToOne
private Map<User, Coordinate> labelledIn;
...
}

@Entity
class User {
...
@OneToMany (mappedBy ="labelledIn") 
private Set<Photo> labelledPhotos;
...
}

@Embedded 
class Coordinate { ... }
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.redex.model.Photo.labelledIn references an unknown entity: java.util.Map
```

Can I map this qualified association in my database? If I can't, how can I do this in a different way?

Comment: A Map contains several values. It's a collection. It makes no sense to have a ManyToOne on a Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
@OneToMany
private Map<User, Coordinate> labelledIn;
```

instead `@ManyToOne`.
As @JB Nizet said, there's no point in having many-to-one relation to a collection.

For more details have a look here: [2.2.5.3.4. Indexed collections (List, Map)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-collections-overview).

Comment: I never saw a `Map` within any relationship between two entities. You're sure it works?

Comment: @sp00m Have a look here (ch 2.2.5.3.4. Indexed collections (List, Map): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association

Comment: I have to do a new design because this classes are wrong. Thanks for the answer anyway. You helped me to realise where was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Such a relationship can only refer to other JPA entities. If you want `one user -> many photos` and `one photo -> one user`, you have to try something like this:

```
class User {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Photo> photos;
}

class Photo {
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
}
```